# Best way to rebase using SVN and Intellij IDEA (12)

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, rebase

I often stuck rebasing a branch with our trunk, mostly if the trunk brings a lot of changes. I personally prefer git but my company is using svn here. 
Can anyone share his experience how to rebase the best using IntelliJ IDEA and svn. At the moment I am using IDEA 12.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/integrating-changes-to-branch.html

It seems these instructions are aimed at integrating a child branch back to a parent (e.g. trunk) but I'm sure the approach is is similar for a rebase (a.k.a integrating from parent to child).

Comment: Woohoo, comments! :D
After further investigation, it seems VCS -> Merge from.. may be the more appropriate option. You can manual select csubmites that have been made to the parent branch and merge them to your working branch.

Comment: To clarify, you need to go VCS -> Merge from... -> _Changes pane popup_ -> Merge From...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean merging branch to trunk?